# Dependency module fails to load resource when used in the IT module

Tags: spring, maven, resources, multi-module

I'm working on a multi-module project which contains a service and an integration-tests module.
In the service module there is a service for some reset password functionality, based on [Spring greenhouse](https://github.com/spring-projects/greenhouse/tree/master/src/main/java/com/springsource/greenhouse/reset) which is using a template file which is expected to be loaded on initialization. While trying to solve this issue I changed slightly the initialization of the class based on the loaded file and moved it to xml configuration:

```
<bean id="resetPasswordMailMessageConverter" class="com.myapp.service.reset.ResetPasswordMailMessageConverter">
    <constructor-arg name="resource">
        <value>classpath*:**/spring/reset-password.st</value>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>
```

The service works fine once deployed and used in tomcat but there are issues when integration tests are executed : **`Unable to read template resource class path resource [classpath*:**/spring/reset-password.st]`**
I placed that file in both places `serviceModule/META-INF/spring/` and `integrationTestsModule/META-INF/spring/` but still it can't be found.

I placed some code both in service and in integration tests where I export the result of `ClassLoader.getSystemResources("META-INF")` and noticed that in both cases the `integrationModule/target/test-classes/META-INF` and the `.m2/repository/../serviceModule.jar!META-INF` are included in the exported path and the file is contained inside both `META-INF/spring/` but not found.

I tried also keeping the file in the same package with the converter and initializing converter's resource as `new ClassPathResource("reset-password.st", getClass().getClassLoader())` or `new ClassPathResource("reset-password.st")` but didn't work.

The structure of the project is `mainModule`->[`mainSubmoduleA`->[`serviceModule`, `integrationTestsModule`, etc], `mainSubmoduleB`[other modules]]

Any idea?

There's a basic layout of the project structure
[image]

Parts of the pom files:

main:

```
...........

<groupId>com.myapp</groupId>
<artifactId>mainModule</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>pom</packaging>
.............
<modules>
    <module>mainSubmoduleA</module>
    <module>mainSubmoduleB</module>
</modules>
```

mainSubmoduleA:

```
..............
<parent>
    <groupId>com.myapp</groupId>
    <artifactId>mainModule</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>
.........

<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.myapp.mainsuba</groupId>
<artifactId>mainSubmoduleA</artifactId>
<packaging>pom</packaging>
<name>mainSubmoduleA</name>
..........

<modules>
  <module>subModuleAA</module>
</modules>
...............
```

subModuleAA:

```
<parent>
  <groupId>com.myapp.mainsuba</groupId>
  <artifactId>mainSubmoduleA</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>

<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.myapp.mainsuba.subaa</groupId>
<artifactId>subModuleAA</artifactId>
<packaging>pom</packaging>
<name>subModuleAA</name>
..........

<modules>
  <module>service</module>
  <module>web</module>
  <module>integration</module>
</modules>
```

service:

```
<parent>
  <groupId>com.myapp.mainsuba.subaa</groupId>
  <artifactId>subModuleAA</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.myapp.mainsuba.service</groupId>
<artifactId>service</artifactId>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
<name>service</name>
```

web:

```
<parent>
  <groupId>com.myapp.mainsuba.subaa</groupId>
  <artifactId>subModuleAA</artifactId>
 <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.myapp.mainsuba.web</groupId>
<artifactId>web</artifactId>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<name>web</name>
```

integration:

```
<parent>
  <groupId>com.myapp.mainsuba.subaa</groupId>
  <artifactId>subModuleAA</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>

<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<artifactId>integration</artifactId>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
<name>integration</name>
<description>Integration Tests</description>
```

Comment: Can you show your folder layout and your pom files...

Comment: @khmarbaise I enriched the description, hope it helps..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chris,

try setting the resource value without any ant-style wildcard matchers. I.e.:

```
<value>META-INF/spring/reset-password.st</value>
```

More info on wildcard restrictions can be found here: [Other notes relating to wildcards](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/resources.html#resources-wildcards-in-path-other-stuff)

Comment: Thanks @anestis-georgiadis, it looks like I tried almost everything except for that :)